# Ask new question for slightly updated context

Tags: accepted-answer, discussion

Should I ask a new question when I have the exact same problem, but my context has changed slightly, and the accepted solution no longer works?

([Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5702168/linq-to-sql-query-to-determine-if-value-starts-with-numeric) in .. question... The new "context" is that I have changed from Linq2SQL to Subsonic. And this breaks the accepted answer.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes.

If you link to the old question and make it clear that

a) your context **is** different and

b) the accepted answer **doesn't** work

you should be OK.