# Reposting after a misguided edit?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

So I saw on [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9632/is-it-ok-to-repost-a-question-that-only-gained-3-views-in-2-days) that you should be reposting after a misguided question, but you should edit with new information. I posted a question on SO and was asked for clarification (more data). When I followed up on it, I erroneously believed that in the process of providing the data, I had found the root cause of the problem, and elucidated this in my edit (the post is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12417379/matlab-svds-not-converging) for anyone interested).

However, I have since discovered that the only reason it seemed like the problem was fixed was due to an issue with scaling that I had overlooked. Now I still have my original question, but the question posted is quite stale and likely anyone who was paying attention to it considers it resolved. In this case, should I be re-posting it because my edit was misguided, or just post a second edit and hope for the best?

Comment: My 2c: because the question hasn't been answered, update the question, remove all the now obsolete information, maybe update the title too. It'll get bumped and it will still be on the unanswered queue in any case. (Updating the title will make the link appear blue again for people who have already visited - this may come across as a bait & switch but your updated question should clearly indicate that the post has gone through revisions.) My advice would be different if anyone had already answered.

Answer (score 1):

If you manage to solve your own problem without relying on other answers then you should be posting the solution that you found as an answer to your own question and marking it as the answer.  This will help make that information available for future readers as well as making it clear that the problem has been entirely resolved.  You should not simply edit the question to indicate that the issue is resolved or add an answer to the question.

When you are prompted for further information in comments, or if you simply think of (or discover) new information that you feel is relevant to the question you should edit it into the question.  You should not just leave that information in comments; all important information in the post should be in either a question or an answer; not in comments.

If your problem hasn't actually changed, but you have simply learned more about it you really shouldn't be posting a new question.  You should simply be editing the question to add the additional information.

You should not be re-posting a question just because it has gone a while without being answered.  When you edit the question it will be re-bumped in the 'activity' view of that tag, so it will get increased visibility.  If you are having trouble getting answers/views for your question you can add a bounty to it to get additional attention.  Re-posting the question would just be making a duplicate that will need to be closed.

Comment: Is this like a stock answer or something? There's nothing in the provided link about posting in comments. I usually wait to answer my own questions until I have it 100% working, which this clearly wasn't.

Comment: @Paul No, it's not a stock answer, I spent quite a while writing it up for you.  It is however designed to apply to the general case and apply to other similar situations, not just this one question.  Having said that, I did read your particular question and made sure that this all applies appropriately to it.