# How should we handle a question which was deleted and reasked?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, deleted-questions

A user has asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20070129/2024761) which did not receive much attention, and thus the user deleted the post. After some time, the user asked the [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20070830/2024761) (with just slight changes to the title and a tag change), so that it could receive a bit more attention. The strange thing is that the question was not downvoted or poorly written, and yet the user deleted the original post.

Now, since the original question was deleted, I could not mark the new one as a duplicate (it threw an error). My question is, how do we handle such questions? Just let them be as such or let the user know about it or is there another way to handle such situations?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Do nothing.

The first, original was deleted - you can't really know why, and for most people, once deleted, if they don't have a link to the deleted question, it is as good as gone.

So, a new question (sure, identical to the first) was asked. Considering that the original had no votes, hardly any views and no answers, we lost nothing by it being deleted.

If someone ends up deleting many of their posts in a short amount of time, an automatic flag will alert moderators to this fact and a mod will take a look, so people who *really* abuse this will be found out.

Comment: But if he does it regularly, we can ask them to not do it as it may send you on the storm of post ban. Should we flag in such situation?

Comment: But what if the user keeps doing that till no answer is  provided? Isn't that wrong?

Comment: @R.J - for the one time? I don't see a problem. Even if they do this a few times? Once they get an upvoted answer, they can't delete. If they get downvoted enough, they will get q-banned.

Comment: @hims056 - Only if the questions get downvoted that may cause a q-ban. Can't see that happening if there were no votes on a post.

Comment: It happened only once here, but say a user never gets any downvote or an upvoted answer and keep doing this till they get am answer which suits them, wouldn't it be wrong to game the system like this, to get the question on the top always by re creating it?

Comment: @R.J - I really don't have strong feelings about it. There are better ways to get attention and frankly chances that the strategy will backfire (over multiple questions) are high.

Answer (score 3):

I think deleting and re-asking the same question is done to give a question additional exposure on a site’s front page. Doing this means that another question gets less exposure than it would otherwise.

Consequently, it is a behavior that I think warrants flagging a moderator so that they can undelete the original question and make the second a duplicate of it.

Comment: Related: [Is it OK to “repost” a question that hasn't gotten many views?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/9632/289691)